# How to prevent Word from creating hidden bookmarks when inserting grouped rows from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, bookmarks

I have an Excel worksheet with data grouped by rows that I want to insert into Word. The problem is that, after pasting the range in Word, when I update the table of contents each cell of the table will be associated with a hidden bookmark and added to the table of contents.

Is this an expected behavior and is there a way to prevent it from happening ?

Steps to reproduce :

- In Excel, insert data into some cells (even only one cell should work), group it by row and copy
- In Word, paste the data and insert a table of contents
- The data pasted should appear as items in the table and as hidden bookmarks in the bookmark window

Comment: Can you please let us know what the settings of your ToC are. Is it using styles or levels to determine what will be in it?. What style is the text in your table? What level? A screen cap or two may also be useful

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks to your comment I dug deeper and came up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to cybernetic.nomad's comment I dug deeper and found the problem and a solution.

The ToC uses the `\u` switch, here is the complete field code : `TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u`.

From the [office support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) :

> **\u**
>
> Builds a table of contents from paragraphs whose formatting includes
> outline levels applied directly, in paragraph settings.

Indeed there is an outline level directly applied in the pasted data : "Niveau 1" (Level 1) which I have to change to "Corps de texte" (Body) for the pasted data to disappear from the ToC, see image below.

[image]

The level associated with the text in Word is the same as the level of the group in Excel :

[image]

To prevent this from happening I chose to paste in Word while choosing to keep the destination's style.